# Fast Data structure for finding strict subsets (from a given list)

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, set

I have a large set of sets e.g. `{{2,4,5} , {4,5}, ...}.`
Given one of these subsets, I would like to iterate through all other subsets which are strict subsets of this subset.  That is, if I am interested in set `A`, e.g. `{2,4,5}`, I want to find all sets `B` where the relative complement  `B / A = {},` the empty set.  Some possibilities could be `{2,4}`, `{2,5}` but not `{2,3}`

I could of course search linearly and check each time, but am looking for an efficient data structure both for the larger set and the subset (if it matters).  The number of subsets is typically in the 10s of thousands, but if it makes a difference I would be interested in cases where it could be in the hundreds of millions.  The size of the subsets is typically in 10s.

I am programming in C++

Thanks

Comment: What are the elements?  How large is their domain, i.e. how many different values can there be in total?

Comment: The elements are nodes in connected communities of a graph.  For all intents and purposes they can be treated as integers from 0 up to maximum which is in 10s.

Comment: Then you likely should represent you sets as `std::bitset` or, if you want to be generic, `boost::dynamic_bitset`.  "A is subset of B" is then simply A & ~B == 0.  Do you need to find all the sets B for many different A or just a couple?  I.e. does it make sense to create a large structure beforehands, or maybe it is enough to make a few exhaustive iterations for different A?

Comment: Is the data static? (Can you add new elements to the set? Can you modify existing elements of the set?)

Comment: @yi_h: 10s is a number between 10-99, I believe. Similar to 100s, a number between 100-999.

Comment: @doublep: Thanks, but using a bitset or many other means I can find out if one set is a subset of another.  The problem is I have a large list of sets, and for a given set I would like to iterate through all those which are subsets.  @yi_h, The data is static, and PengOne is correct about what I mean by 10s.

Comment: @doubleep: Using a bitset (either) still makes the subset test O(n). It's just O(n) with a low constant.

Answer (score 10):

Mathematically, you should construct the [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) for your sets, which will be the partially ordered set with vertices your sets and arrows given by containment. Essentially, you want to create a [directed, acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) with an arrow `A --> B` if `A` strictly contains `B` and there is no `C` such that `A` strictly contains `C`  and `C` strictly contains `B`.

This is actually going to be a ranked poset, meaning that you can keep track of "levels" of the digraph based on the cardinality of the sets. This is sort of like creating a hash table to jump to the right set.

From `A`, just do a BFS down the graph to find all proper subsets of `A`.

*How to implement this:* (in pseudocode)

```
for (C in sets) {
    for (B in HasseDiagram at rank rank(C)+1) {
      if (C contains B)
        addArrow(C,B)
    }
    for (A in HasseDiagram at rank rank(C)+1) {
      if (C contains A)
        addArrow(A,C)
    }
    addToDiagram(C)
}
```

To make this and all the subroutines fast, you can encode each set an a binary where digit `i` is `1` if `i` is in `C` and `0` otherwise. This makes testing containment and determining rank trivial.

The above method works **if you have all possible subsets**. Since you may be missing some, you'll have to check more things. For the pseudocode, you'll need to change `rank(C)-1` to the largest integer `l < rank(C)` such that some element of the HasseDiagram has rank `l`, and similarly for `rank(C)+1`. Then, when you're adding the set `C` to the diagram:

1. If `A` covers `C`, then you only need to check lower ranked sets `B` that are also covered by `A`.
2. If `C` covers `B`, then you only need to check higher ranked sets `A` that also cover by `B`.

By "`X` covers `Y`" I mean there is an arrow `X -> Y`, not just a path.

Furthermore, when you insert `C` between `A` and `B` using one of the above checks, you will need to remove the arrow `A --> B` when you add `A --> C` and `C --> B`.

Comment: Actually, this is the exact graph I am trying to create, I think.  I thought the way about doing it would be for all sets to search for sets which are strict subsets.  Thanks for the terminology!

Comment: @zenna: You can walk through the sets, creating the graph as you go using a bisection algorithm to insert the set into the proper spot. I've implemented this in Maple before and it was pretty effective, but it used many of their graph functions. I'll see if I can distill the idea.

Comment: To clarify, you say I should construct a Hasse diagram, I guess my question indirectly is, how does one construct a Hasse graph fast?  It's worth considering that I do not consider all possible subsets, I have a large but smaller set of possibilities.

Comment: Sorry I wrote that comment before I saw your response.  with the bisection method, the bisected sets may well not be valid for me.  I guess I could have some rejection policy. Hmm

Comment: @PengOne: I am confused as to whether the pseudo-code actually works.  Consider `{{1}, {2}, {3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}}`.  Then `{1}` has rank 1, `{1, 2, 3}` has rank 3, `{1}` is a subset of `{1, 2, 3}` and there are no intervening subsets.  Your `first_rank_below` and `first_rank_above` makes me think that you could miss this relation.

Comment: @btilly: You're correct, there is a problem here. I need to remove connections when inserting a new intermediate. Thanks for pointing this out. The pseudocode assumes that you have **all** subsets, so that will work, but not the generalization. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest storing all of the sets in a tree.  Each node of the tree would represent all sets that contained a specified initial list of integers.  I would have the nodes contain the following pieces of information:

1. The number of additional elements in the smallest set at this point or below in the tree.  (0 means that this node is in the tree.)
2. A bitset representing the intersection of all subsets below this one in the tree.
3. A pointer to an array mapping larger integers to subtrees that contain that as the next element.  As a special case, if there is only one subset below this one in the tree, this pointer could be null.  (There is no need to fill out unpopulated parts of the tree.)

Given this tree, and a subset you can do a search with recursion and backtracking for all subsets of the set.  In your search you start with the first element of the subset, look for all subsets that contain that element, then you search for all subsets that don't contain that element.

Building this tree takes time and space at most `O(n * m * k)` where `n` is the number of subsets `m` is the average number of elements per subset, and `k` is the size of the universe of elements that can be in the sets.  With random sets of sets that are much smaller than the possible universe of subsets of your `k` elements you won't construct most of the tree, and it will take `O(n * m)` for your tree.

In theory traversing this tree could be time `O(n)`.  **But** in practice you'll trim branches of the tree fairly early, and won't traverse most of the other subsets.  A back of the envelope calculation suggests that if you have `n` random sets out of a `k` element universe with `n << 2k` then a search of the tree is `O(n0.5k)`.  (At each integer, half the time it is in your set you're searching for subsets of and you split your search into 2, and half the time it isn't in your set and you eliminate half of your space.  After `j` integers you've got `2j/2` searches going of sets of sets of size `2-jn`.  Thus by the time you get the searches down to single other subsets to compare with, there are `O(n0.5)` searches going.  The final comparison of bitmaps is `O(k)`.)

**Note**: I'm convinced by this back of the envelope calculation that the average performance is `o(n0.5+epsilon)` for every `epsilon > 0`, but the convergence is very slow.  More precisely I suspect that the arithmetic average of the performance is `n0.5 + O(sqrt(log(n))))`.  But that `sqrt(log(n))` piece takes a long time to converge.

Note that using the number of additional elements in the smallest set at this point or below in the tree lets your search trivially filter out all sets that are too large to be subsets.  Depending on your dataset, this may or may not lead to useful speedups.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical of the O(sqrt(n)) over head calculation.  Could you go through that in more detail?  Specifically, how do you estimate the probability that you won't visit a particular branch?  Other than that, good answer.

Comment: @Mikola: At each integer in your universe, half the other subsets contain it, and half don't.  Thus each of your recursive searches on average is cut in half.  So if there are 1 million other subsets, it takes looking at about 20 integers to make your surviving searches be of 1 other set each.  On average 10 of those integers are in your set, and 10 are not, leading to an average of 1024 searches.

Comment: @Mikola: However this is a median, not an arithmetic average.  If only 8 of those integers are in your set, then you have only 256 searches going.  If 12 are in your set, then you have 4k searches going.  This asymmetry is not small.  I will add a comment about this.

Comment: I think we are using different n's here.  My n is the number of elements in the universal set (ie the union over all the sets we are querying over).  It seems like you are using n to refer to the number of sets in the set of all sets which are being searched on.  I would agree with you that on average the number of sets returned  be O(sqrt(#sets being searched on)) assuming a uniform distribution, however the overhead of searching this set is the number of additional nodes visited in the tree (aka its height per element).

Comment: This overhead should be O(log(sqrt(#sets being searched))), which is asymptotically O(#elements in universe/2).

Comment: @Mikola: We are indeed using different `n`'s.  Mine is the number of sets, `m` is the average size of the sets, and `k` is the size of the universe.

Comment: @Mikola: I don't see where you are getting your relationship between the number of sets and the size of the universe.  The size of the universe puts a maximum on the number of sets, but those parameters seem otherwise unrelated to me.

Comment: @btilly:  Hmm...  You are right.  I need to think about this a bit more carefully.  I took out my analysis from my answer because I no longer believe it is correct.  However, I can show definitively that rearranging the entries leads to fewer node traversals in all cases; but I am no longer sure exactly how to quantify exactly how big this change would be....

Answer (score 3):

The approach suggested by PengOne would work, but it is not very efficient.  To see why it fails, consider the following pathological example:

Suppose you have a universe U, which has n distinct elements, and let the set of all the sets you are searching over consist of all subsets of U with exactly k elements.  Then it is true that no pair of sets here are strictly contained in one another; and so in the worst case you would have to search over all n choose k possible sets!  In other words, using his proposed data structure is no better than a naive linear search in the worst case.

Clearly you can do much better than this, and the correct data structure to use would be a trie:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

To adapt a trie to work for sets instead of just strings, it is sufficient to fix an ordering on the elements of the universal set, then encode each of your subsets as a binary string of finite length, where the ith character is 0 or 1 depending on whether the set contains the ith element.  Here is an implementation in python

```
import math

class SetTree:
    def __init__(self, index, key, left, right):
        self.index = index
        self.key = key
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

cached_trees = { }
cached_index = 2

def get_index(T):
    if isinstance(T, SetTree):
        return T.index
    if T:
        return 1
    return 0        

def make_set_tree(key, left, right):
    global cached_trees, cached_index
    code = (key, get_index(left), get_index(right))
    if not code in cached_trees:
        cached_trees[code] = SetTree(cached_index, key, left, right)
        cached_index += 1
    return cached_trees[code]

def compute_freqs(X):
    freqs, total = {}, 0
    for S in X:
        for a in S:
            if a in freqs:
                freqs[a] += 1
            else:
                freqs[a] = 1
            total += 1
    U = [ (-f, a) for a,f in freqs.items() ]
    U.sort()
    return U

#Constructs the tree recursively
def build_tree_rec(X, U):
    if len(X) == 0:
        return False
    if len(U) == 0:
        return True

    key = U[0][1]

    left_elems = [ S for S in X if key in S]

    if len(left_elems) > 0:
        return make_set_tree(key,
            build_tree_rec(left_elems, U[1:]),
            build_tree_rec([ S for S in X if not key in S ], U[1:]))

    return build_tree_rec(X, U[1:])

#Build a search tree recursively
def build_tree(X):
    U = compute_freqs(X)
    return build_tree_rec(X, U)


#Query a set tree to find all subsets contained in a given set
def query_tree(T, S):
    if not isinstance(T, SetTree):
        return [ [] ] if T else []
    if T.key in S:
        return [ U + [ T.key ] for U in query_tree(T.left, S) ] + query_tree(T.right, S)
    return query_tree(T.right, S)

#Debugging function: Converts a tree to a tuple for printing
def tree_to_tuple(T):
    if isinstance(T, SetTree):
        return (T.key, tree_to_tuple(T.left), tree_to_tuple(T.right))
    return T
```

Now here is an example usage:

```
In [15]: search_tree = set_search.build_tree(set_family)

In [16]: set_search.tree_to_tuple(search_tree)
Out[16]: 
(2,
 (4, (5, True, True), (5, True, (3, True, False))),
 (4, (5, True, False), (1, True, False)))

In [17]: set_search.query_tree(search_tree, set([2,3,4,5]))
Out[17]: [[5, 4, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2], [3, 2], [5, 4]]

In [18]: set_search.query_tree(search_tree, set([1,2,3,4,5]))
Out[18]: [[5, 4, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2], [3, 2], [5, 4], [1]]

In [19]: set_search.query_tree(search_tree, set([2,4,5]))
Out[19]: [[5, 4, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2], [5, 4]]

In [20]: set_search.query_tree(search_tree, set([2,5]))
Out[20]: [[5, 2]]

In [21]: set_search.query_tree(search_tree, set([1]))
Out[21]: [[1]]

In [22]: set_search.query_tree(search_tree, set([15]))
Out[22]: []
```

Note that the amount of work performed by query_tree is proportional to the size of the subtree which represents the set of all results returned by query_tree.  Thus our goal is to compute the size of one of the subtries (on average) and then as a secondary goal to minimize this quantity.  One way to do this is to reorder the elements of the universal in terms of descending frequency, so that they are repeated as few times as possible in the lower levels of the tree.  This optimization is also done in the above code.  A secondary optimization is to cache the trees which have already been searched to avoid having to redo unnecessary work.

EDIT:  Just after I got done typing this up, I saw btilly's answer, which is comes to more or less the same conclusion about the problem (modulo some technical nitpicks which I have moved into the comments on his post.)

EDIT 2:  Realized that this is really just a special case of a binary decision diagram.  Don't really have enough energy to fix the write up right now, so will leave it as is.  Perhaps fix it tomorrow.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram

Comment: I was about to comment that our solutions are very similar (I'm amazed that they were posted so close together given how long the question was open), but I think your complexity analysis needs more work.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually working on it, but I figured I had enough written to post an early version quickly.  I am currently fleshing it out with some more details.

Comment: @Mikola: A Hasse Diagram is valid for **any poset**. It doesn't need to be the poset of all subsets. So what I am constructing is indeed the Hasse diagram for the poset given by containment for his sets. Moreover, once the Hasse diagram is in place, the case you describe is trivially solved since there are no children to search. Setting up the Hasse diagram is time consuming, though.

Comment: @zenna: Yeah, I modified the code a bit to incorporate some improvements and forgot to update the example.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. I like the Hasse diagram approach PengOne suggests but I think you can build the Hasse diagram really quickly using a prime number trick. Lets say the union of all of the sets results in natural numbers 1 to N. Map each of these numbers with corresponding primes, like:

```
PrimeMap [1] = 2;
PrimeMap [2] = 3;
PrimeMap [3] = 5;
```

Next, caluclate a 'score' for each set by multiplying each of the prime numbers corresponding to the number in the set. For instance a set {1,2,3} would have a score 2*3*5 = 30. Now, for a set A to be a proper subset of another set B score(A) must divide score(B) (scores for {1,2}, {2,3} and {1,3} are 6, 15 and 10, each of which divide 30). Use this score to build your Hasse diagram.

**Edit: This seems like one of the nice theoretical solutions. Probably not the way to go. Bitsets as suggested by yi_H is just as good and does not suffer from big integer troubles.**

Comment: that won't work, with 10s of elements in a subset... you have to check 2^(n-1) different combinations.

Comment: um not really, its a set, the order doesn't matter. The set {2,1} and {1,2} would have the same score. Why would you need yo check 2^(n-1) combinations?

Comment: This is an interesting solution.  I am not sure why yi_H suggests you would need to check 2^(n-1) solutions.  I am wondering if there are any caveats though.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood it. But why is this better than a bitfield check? It requires definitely more computation

Comment: There is one glaring one alright. The size of the numbers when you multiply them can get huge. There are several workarounds (I think) such as doing the math in modulo some-large-number space but it leads to additional complications. A bigint library would do the trick as long as your numbers don't get too big.

Comment: Actually never mind, you're right, the bitfield check would probably be just as fast (and faster on bigints)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this python library that implements Hasse diagrams python-lattice][1](https://code.google.com/p/python-lattice/)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this does only really implement them for graphing, not in any efficient algorithmic sense.

Comment: Looks cute, but seems to be a bit out of date?