# Efficient algorithm for finding all maximal subsets

Tags: algorithm, set

I have a collection of unique sets (represented as bit masks) and would like to eliminate all elements that are proper subsets of another element.  For example:

```
input = [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {}]
output = [{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4}]
```

I have not been able to find a standard algorithm for this, or even a name for this problem, so I am calling it "maximal subsets" for lack of anything else.  Here is an O(n^2) algorithm (in Python for concreteness), assuming `is_subset_func` is O(1):<sup>1</sup>

```py
def eliminate_subsets(a, cardinality_func, is_subset_func):
    out = []
    for element in sorted(a, reverse=True, key=cardinality_func):
        for existing in out:
            if is_subset_func(element, existing):
                break
        else:
            out.append(element)
    return out
```

Is there a more efficient algorithm, hopefully O(n log n) or better?

---

<sup>1</sup>  For bit masks of constant size, as is true in my case, `is_subset_func` is just `element & existing == element`, which runs in constant time.

Comment: If the range of elements is limited, you can get a big constant factor speedup by representing the sets as bit masks (x subset of y iff y == x|y).  Also note your function is not O(n^2) unless `is_subset_func` is O(1), which seems unlikely.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I just clarified the post now.  I am using bit masks and therefore `is_subset_func` is O(1) since it is just `(element & existing == element)`.

Comment: You may wish to look at the answers to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512400

Comment: Nice find, @PeterdeRivaz. It seems this problem can be solved by inserting all sets in a set-trie, and then enumerating all leaves.

Comment: Thanks @PeterdeRivaz and Tinctorious.  That does look like a good solution, though *much* more complicated.  I'll try to figure out how to code it up.  If either of you want to post some psuedo- or Python code as an answer, I'll gladly accept it if no one else posts something better.

Comment: I'm testing my code. This might take a while with all these fireworks outside.

Comment: Hmmm... a trie might not be as easy as it initially seemed. My appraoch doesn't even work, and I know why. I'll have take some sleep over this for now.

Comment: I don't think you can do less than O(n^2) since the length of solution can itself be O(n^2) in the worst case. But you can definitely bring down the constant weight down by applying heuristics mentioned below.

Comment: @ElKamina, I'm using n as the number of sets, not the total number of elements in all the sets, so the length of the solution is only O(n).

Comment: Hi, I think you are making a wrong assumption here. If you delete the or unset the element which is a subset of another element then the complexity of your algorithm is not **O(n^2)** it will be **O(n*j) : where j <= n**

Comment: I'm pretty confident now that the trie solution given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6514461/824425) will **not** work for this problem. I'm working on an alternative.

Comment: The alternative idea didn't work. I think anything shaped like a tree might not work, and you will need a DAG for this. If this is true, this might raise the lower bound on the temporal and spatial complexity of the problem above `O(kn)`.

Comment: Why does question like those not belong to [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/ "cs.stackexchange") ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suppose you label all the input sets.

```
A={1, 2, 3}, B={1, 2}, C={2, 3}, D={2, 4}, E={}
```

Now build intermediate sets, one per element in the universe, containing the labels of the sets where it appears:

```
1={A,B}
2={A,B,C,D}
3={A,C}
4={D}
```

Now for each input set compute the intersection of all the label sets of its elements:

```
For A, {A,B} intesect {A,B,C,D} intersect {A,C} = {A}   (*)
```

If the intersection contains some label other than for the set itself, then it's s a subset of that set.  Here there is no other element, so the answer is no.  But,

```
For C, {A,B,C,D} intersect {A,C} = {A,C}, which means that it's a subset of A.
```

The cost of this method depends on the implementation of sets.  Suppose bitmaps (as you hinted).  Say there are n input sets of maximum size m and |U| items in the universe.  Then the intermediate set construction produces |U| sets of size n bits, so there is O(|U|n) time to initialize them.  Setting the bits requires O(nm) time.  Computing each intersection as at `(*)` above requires O(mn); O(mn^2) for all.

Putting all these together we have O(|U|n) + O(nm) +O(mn^2) = O(|U|n + mn^2). Using the same conventions, your "all pairs" algorithm is O(|U|^2 n^2). Since m <= |U|, this algorithm is asymptotically faster. It's likely to be faster in practice as well because there's no elaborate bookkeeping to add constant factors.

**Addition: On Line Version**

The OP asked if there is an online version of this algorithm, i.e. one where the set of maximal sets can be maintained incrementally as input sets arrive one-by-one.  The answer seems to be yes.  The intermediate sets tell us quickly if a new set is a *subset* of one already seen.  But how to tell quickly if it's a *superset*? And, if so, of which existing maximal sets? For in this case those maximal sets are no longer maximal and must be replaced by the new one.

The key is to note that `A` is a superset of `B` iff `A'` is a subset of `B'` (the tick' denoting set complement).

Following this inspiration, we maintain the intermediate set as before.  When a new input set `S` arrives, do the same test as described above: Let `I(e)` be the intermediate set for input element `e`.  Then this test is

```
For X = \intersect_{e \in S} . I(e), |X| > 0
```

(In this case it's greater than zero rather than one as above because `S` is not yet in `I`.)  If the test succeeds, then the new set is a (possibly improper) subset of an existing maximal set, so it can be discarded.

Otherwise we must add `S` as a new maximal set, but before doing this, compute:

```
Y = \intersect_{e \in S'} . I'(e) = ( \union_{e \in S'} . I(e) )'
```

where again the tick' is set complement. The union form may be a bit faster to compute. `Y` contains the maximal sets that have been superceded by `S`. They must be removed from the maximal collection and from `I`. Finally add `S` as a maximal set and update `I` with `S`'s elements.

Let's work through our example.  When `A` arrives, we add it to `I` and have

```
1={A}  2={A}  3={A}
```

When `B` arrives, we find `X = {A} intersect {A} = {A}`, so throw `B` away and continue.  The same happens for `C`.  When `D` arrives we find `X = {A} intersect {} = {}`, so continue with `Y = I'(1) intersect I'(3) = {} intersect {}`.  This correctly tells us that maximal set `A` is not contained in `D`, so there is nothing to delete.  But it must be added as a new maximal set, and `I` becomes

```
1={A}  2={A,D}  3={A}  4={D}
```

The arrival of `E` causes no change.  Posit the arrival then of a new set `F={2, 3, 4, 5}`.  We find

```
X = {A} isect {A,D} isect {A} isect {D} isect {}
```

so we cannot throw `F` away. Continue with

```
Y = \intersect_{e in {1}} I'(e) = I'(1) = {D}
```

This tells us `D` is a subset of `F`, so should be discarded while `F` is added, leaving

```
1={A} 2={A,F} 3={A,F} 4={F} 5={F}
```

The computation of the complements is both tricky and nice due to the algorithm's online nature.  The universe for input complements need only include input elements seen so far.  The universe for intermediate sets consists only of tags of sets in the current maximal collection. For many input streams the size of this set will stabilize or decrease over time.

I hope this is helpful.

**Summary**

The general principle at work here is a powerful idea that crops of often in algorithm design.  It's the reverse map.  Whenever you find yourself doing a linear search to find an item with a given attribute, consider building a map from the attribute back to item.  Often it is cheap to construct this map, and it strongly reduces search time.  The premier example is a permutation map `p[i]` that tells you what position the `i`'th element will occupy after an array is permuted.  If you need to search out the item that ends up in a given location `a`, you must search `p` for `a`, a linear time operation.  On the other hand, an inverse map `pi` such that `pi[p[i]] == i` takes no longer to compute than does `p` (so its cost is "hidden"), but `pi[a]` produces the desired result in constant time.

**Implementation by Original Poster**

```py
import collections
import operator
from functools import reduce # only in Python 3

def is_power_of_two(n):
    """Returns True iff n is a power of two.  Assumes n > 0."""
    return (n & (n - 1)) == 0

def eliminate_subsets(sequence_of_sets):
    """Return a list of the elements of `sequence_of_sets`, removing all
    elements that are subsets of other elements.  Assumes that each
    element is a set or frozenset and that no element is repeated."""
    # The code below does not handle the case of a sequence containing
    # only the empty set, so let's just handle all easy cases now.
    if len(sequence_of_sets) <= 1:
        return list(sequence_of_sets)
    # We need an indexable sequence so that we can use a bitmap to
    # represent each set.
    if not isinstance(sequence_of_sets, collections.Sequence):
        sequence_of_sets = list(sequence_of_sets)
    # For each element, construct the list of all sets containing that
    # element.
    sets_containing_element = {}
    for i, s in enumerate(sequence_of_sets):
        for element in s:
            try:
                sets_containing_element[element] |= 1 << i
            except KeyError:
                sets_containing_element[element] = 1 << i
    # For each set, if the intersection of all of the lists in which it is
    # contained has length != 1, this set can be eliminated.
    out = [s for s in sequence_of_sets
           if s and is_power_of_two(reduce(
               operator.and_, (sets_containing_element[x] for x in s)))]
    return out
```

Comment: Nice!  I coded this up and it does work much faster, especially for large inputs.  I'm going to wait a day or two before accepting in case someone posts a better algorithm.

Comment: Would you mind if I edit your post and include my Python implementation?

Comment: Done.  I switched to using an actual `set` type as input, rather than bitmasks, because it is easier to enumerate the elements that are included in the set with a `set` rather than an `int` representing a bitmask.

Comment: If you think of a way to make it an online algorithm, such that you only need to traverse `sequence_of_sets`, please let me know.  That might help my application.

Comment: I'll think about other algorithms, but I don't think you mean "online". There can't be a true online algorithm for this problem because adding input can cause a previously determined output to be wrong.

Comment: Couldn't an algorithm potentially maintain a list of what the "maximal subsets" are and update it each time a new input comes?  For example, suppose the current output is `{1,2,3} {2,4}`.  If an input of `{1,2,3,4}` comes along, then the algorithm could remove the two old elements and replace them with `{1,2,3,4}`?

Comment: See suggested algorithm above.  I hope you'll code this one, too, though it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Where you say "For all of them we have O(|U|mn)", I believe you mean "For all of them we have O(mn^2)", since (as you say) *each* `(*)` intersection takes O(nm) time -- but you need to perform this step once for each of the n input sets, i.e., n times (not |U| times).  This is exactly the same complexity as the OP's solution, assuming that his `is_subset_func()` is implemented as an O(m) list merge of already-sorted sets.  Have to -1 sorry.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Good catch. I fixed the big O computation. But it's not the same complexity as the OP. We're still ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the update and comment, but I think you're wrong about the OP's solution.  If he uses bitsets then each call to `is_subset_func()` takes just O(|U|) time for O(|U|n^2) time overall, not O(|U|^2) time (as seems implicit in your claim of O(|U|^2*n^2) time overall).  If he used a sorted-list-of-integers representation instead of bitsets, he'd get an overall time complexity of O(mn^2), same as yours.  If you mention this (or convince me I'm wrong!) I'll drop the -1.

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been studied in literature. Given S_1,...,S_k which are subsets of {1,...,n}, Yellin [1] gave an algorithm to find the maximal subset of {S_1,...,S_k} in time O(kdm) where d is the *average* size of the S_i, and m is the cardinality of the the maximal subset of {S_1,...,S_k}. This was later improved for some range of parameters by Yellin and Jutla [2] to O((kd)^2/sqrt(log(kd))). It is believed that a truly sub-quadratic algorithm to this problem does not exist.

[1] Daniel M. Yellin: Algorithms for Subset Testing and Finding Maximal Sets. SODA 1992: 386-392.

[2] Daniel M. Yellin, Charanjit S. Jutla: Finding Extremal Sets in Less than Quadratic Time. Inf. Process. Lett. 48(1): 29-34 (1993).

Comment: you should probably clean up your answer to have good formatting

Comment: See also Fast Algorithms for Finding Extremal Sets by Bayardo & Panda (2011)

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head there is an O(D*N*log(N)) where D is the number of unique numbers.

The recursive function "helper" works as follows:
@arguments is sets and domain (number of unique numbers in sets):
Base cases:

1. If the domain is empty, return
2. If sets is empty or sets has length equal to 1, return

Iterative case:

1. Remove all empty sets from sets
2. Pick an element D in domain
3. Remove D from the domain
4. Separate sets into two sets (set1 & set2) based on whether the set contains D
5. Remove D from each set in sets
6. Set result = union ( helper(set1,domain), helper(set2,domain) )
7. For each set in set1 add D back
8. return result

Note that the runtime depends on the Set implementation used. If a doubly linked list is used to store the set then:

Steps 1-5,7 take O(N)
Step 6's union is O(N*log(N)) by sorting and then merging

Therefore the overall algorithm is O(D*N*log(N))

Here is java code to perform the following

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyMain {

    public static Set<Set<Integer>> eliminate_subsets(Set<Set<Integer>> sets) throws Exception {
        Set<Integer> domain = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (Set<Integer> set : sets) {
            for (Integer i : set) {
                domain.add(i);
            }
        }
        return helper(sets,domain);
    }

    public static Set<Set<Integer>> helper(Set<Set<Integer>> sets, Set<Integer> domain) throws Exception {
        if (domain.isEmpty()) { return sets; }
        if (sets.isEmpty()) { return sets; }
        else if (sets.size() == 1) { return sets; }

        sets.remove(new HashSet<Integer>());

        // Pop some value from domain
        Iterator<Integer> it = domain.iterator();
        Integer splitNum = it.next();
        it.remove();

        Set<Set<Integer>> set1 = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>(); 
        Set<Set<Integer>> set2 = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
        for (Set<Integer> set : sets) {
            if (set.contains(splitNum)) {
                set.remove(splitNum);
                set1.add(set);
            }
            else {
                set2.add(set);
            }
        }

        Set<Set<Integer>> ret = helper(set1,domain);
        ret.addAll(helper(set2,domain));

        for (Set<Integer> set : set1) {
            set.add(splitNum);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Set<Set<Integer>> s=new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
        Set<Integer> tmp = new HashSet<Integer>();
        tmp.add(new Integer(1)); tmp.add(new Integer(2)); tmp.add(new Integer(3));
        s.add(tmp);

        tmp = new HashSet<Integer>();
        tmp.add(new Integer(1)); tmp.add(new Integer(2));
        s.add(tmp);

        tmp = new HashSet<Integer>();
        tmp.add(new Integer(3)); tmp.add(new Integer(4));
        s.add(tmp);
        System.out.println(eliminate_subsets(s).toString());
    }


}
```

*New years is disruptive

Comment: Good idea.  I believe this will be more efficient than my algorithm if D << N.

Comment: You'll still have to check all the guys in List 1 against List 2.  Still a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-process assumptions:

Input set is sorted by descending lengths

Each set is sorted ascending by value

*There is access to a total and length for each set*

### Approach #2 - Use a bucket approach

Same assumptions.
Can uniqueness be assumed? (i.e. there is not {1,4,6},{1,4,6})
Otherwise, you would need to check for distinct at some point, probably once the buckets are created.

semi psuedo

```
List<Set> Sets;//input
List<Set> Output;
List<List<Set>> Buckets;
int length = Sets[0].length;//"by descending lengths"
List<Set> Bucket = new List<Set>();//current bucket

//Place each set with shared length in its own bucket
for( Set set in Sets )
{
 if( set.length == length )//current Bucket
 {
  Bucket.add(set);
 }else//new Bucket
 {
  length = set.length;
  Buckets.Add(Bucket);
  Bucket = new Bucket();
  Bucket.Add(set);
 }
}
Buckets.add(Bucket);



//Based on the assumption of uniqueness, everything in the first bucket is
//larger than every other set and since it is unique, they are not proper subsets
Output.AddRange(Buckets[0]);

//Iterate through the buckets
for( int i = 1; i < Buckets.length; i++ )
{
 List<Set> currentBucket = Buckets[i];

 //Iterate through the sets in the current bucket
 for( int a = 0; a < currentBucket.length; a++ )
 {
  Set currentSet = currentBucket[a];
  bool addSet = true;
  //Iterate through buckets with greater length
  for( int b = 0; b < i; b++ )
  {
   List<Set> testBucket = Buckets[b];

   //Iterate through the sets in testBucket
   for( int c = 0; c < testBucket.length; c++ )
   {
    Set testSet = testBucket[c];
    int testMatches = 0;

    //Iterate through the values in the current set
    for( int d = 0; d < currentSet.length; d++ )
    {
     int testIndex = 0;

     //Iterate through the values in the test set
     for( ; testIndex < testSet.length; testIndex++ )
     {
      if( currentSet[d] < testSet[testIndex] )
      {
       setClear = true;
       break;
      }
      if( currentSet[d] == testSet[testIndex] )
      {
       testMatches++;
       if( testMatches == currentSet.length )
       {
        addSet = false;
        setClear = true;
        break;
       }
      }
     }//testIndex
     if( setClear ) break;
    }//d
    if( !addSet ) break;
   }//c
   if( !addSet ) break;
  }//b
  if( addSet ) Output.Add( currentSet );
 }//a
}//i
```

### Approach #1 (`O( n(n+1)/2 )`) ... not efficient enough

semi psuedo

```
//input Sets
List<Set> results;
for( int current = 0; current < Sets.length; current++ )
{
 bool addCurrent = true;
 Set currentSet = Sets[current];
 for( int other = 0; other < current; other++)
 {
  Set otherSet = Sets[other];
  //is current a subset of other?
  if( currentSet.total > otherSet.total 
   || currentSet.length >= otherSet.length) continue;
  int max = currentSet.length;
  int matches = 0;
  int otherIndex = 0, len = otherSet.length;
  for( int i = 0; i < max; i++ )
  {
   for( ; otherIndex < len; otherIndex++ )
   {
     if( currentSet[i] == otherSet[otherInex] )
     {
      matches++;
      break;
     }
   }
   if( matches == max )
   {
    addCurrent = false;
    break;
   }
  }
  if( addCurrent ) results.Add(currentSet);
 }
}
```

This will take the set of sets, and iterate through each one. With each one, it will iterate through each set in the set again. As the nested iteration takes place, it will compare if the outer set is the same as the nested set (from the inner iteration) (if they are, no checking is done), it will also compare if the outer set has a total greater than the nested set (if the total is greater, then the outer set cannot be a proper subset), it will then compare if the outer set has a smaller amount of items than the nested set.

Once those checks are complete it begins with the first item of the outer set, and compares it with the first item of the nested set. If they are not equal, it will check the next item of the nested set. If they are equal, then it adds one to a counter, and will then compare the next item of the outer set with where it left off in the inner set.

If it reaches a point where the amount of matched comparisons equal the number of items in the outer set, then the outer set has been found to be a proper subset of the inner set. It is flagged to be excluded, and the comparisons are halted.

Comment: I see four `for`-loops, two of them iterating over the input, making it `Ω(n^2)`. This isn't asymptotically better than the solution of the OP, which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Tinctorius - Yes, but the exclusions are what garners efficiency. Although, I think that the nested loop can be made more efficient.

Comment: @Tinctorius - Because the sets are ordered by length, no previous set can be a subset of the current set. This removes a large part of the nested iteration, and makes the worst case scenario of this algorithm O(n log n).

Comment: Ah, *now* I see the `continue`. That changes something, but I still have doubts that it's asymptotically better.

Comment: @TravisJ - I believe @Tinctorius is right.  This is basically the same as my algorithm, which is `O(n^2)`.  Your outer two loops always finish, so you are doing `n*(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)` executions of the second loop.

Comment: @MarkLodato - In fact, it is not `O(n log n)` as I asserted. This will be executed (0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .. + n - 1) which is equivalent to the sum of 0 to i of n which is n(n+1)/2. So this is the efficiency. It is technically twice as fast as yours. For an input of 1000 items, yours will run 1,000,000 times, this will run 500,500 times, and if there were a nlogn solution, it would run 100,000 times. Perhaps `nlogn` can be found with a tree approach as suggested in your question's comments.

Comment: @MarkLodato - See edit for bucket approach. When used on your simple example it would only execute 3 set comparisons. Namely, `{1, 2}` in `{1, 2, 3}`?, `{2, 3}` in `{1, 2, 3}`?, `{2, 4}` in `{1, 2, 3}`?