# Remove python dictionary enteries for keys with values that are a subset of another key

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a dictionary generated using `defaultdict`:

```
{"GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAACGG": ["9/1", "9/2", "1/1.1", "9/2.1"],
 "GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGCC": ["9/2", "9/2.1"],
 "GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGGG": ["1/1", "1/2", "9/1", "1/1.1"]}
```

One of the enteries is a subset of the other in terms of its values:

```
"GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGCC": ["9/2", "9/2.1"]
```

is a subset of

```
"GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAACGG": ["9/1", "9/2", "1/1.1", "9/2.1"]
```

How would I go about collapsing the dictionary so that in the end I would get either of these results?

```
{"GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAACGG": ["9/1", "9/2", "1/1.1", "9/2.1"],
 "GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGGG": ["1/1", "1/2", "9/1", "1/1.1"]}
```

or

```
{["GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAACGG", "GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGCC"]:
    ["9/1", "9/2", "1/1.1", "9/2.1"],
 "GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGGG":
    ["1/1", "1/2", "9/1", "1/1.1"]}
```

Edit:

So as requested this was my attempt:

```
#dd is my defaultdict
for keys, values in dd.iteritems():
        if all(for item in values:
                if item in dd.items():
                    return True
                else:
                    return False):
             print keys
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: Would you like me to post my failed attempts? I need help solving a programing problem that I am stuck on, I don't get how its perceived as off-topic.

Comment: Yes, please; give a [mcve] with inputs and expected *and actual* outputs.

Comment: You don't need to post all attempts, just the one or ones that came closest.

Comment: Here's a hint: You could probably change the list of values into instances of the built-in [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) type which would make it easy to check for subsets, supersets, etc

Comment: @martineau Though I think in this case that would not work, because strings have order (and order is important for setset/superset for strings) , but sets/frozensets do not have order, I believe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is perhaps being overly vigilant, but example code would be helpful. Also, just to clarify, if `A`'s values are a subset of `B`'s values, then you want `A` to be assigned all of `B`'s values, right? What if `A`'s values are a subset of more than one other key's values? Also, I second @martineau's suggestion to use the built-in `set` type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think this is an interresting question since there may be a more efficient solution than just go on and testing if each set is subset of each and every one of the other sets.

Comment: For efficient algorithm for finding which sets one should keep you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106121/efficient-algorithm-for-finding-all-maximal-subsets

Comment: @bebop if `A`'s values are a subset of `B`'s values, then `B` contains all the information of `A` and therefore I think you could just delete A. The values are themselves unique identifiers which will allow me to look up the keys later if I need to.

Comment: Your *"attempt"* isn't even syntactically valid... Once you have it running, what outputs do you get? How do they differ from what you want?

Comment: @Anand: You're correct about lack of ordering. The values can be kept as lists but easily converted, on-the-fly, to sets in order to do the set operations. That's what itzmeontv is doing in his/her answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
mydict = {"GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAACGG": ["9/1", "9/2", "1/1.1", "9/2.1"],
 "GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGCC": ["9/2", "9/2.1"],
 "GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGGG": ["1/1", "1/2", "9/1", "1/1.1"]}

>>>dict([i for i in mydict.items() if not any(set(j).issuperset(set(i[1])) and j!=i[1] for j in mydict.values())])

{'GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAACGG': ['9/1', '9/2', '1/1.1', '9/2.1'],
 'GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGGG': ['1/1', '1/2', '9/1', '1/1.1']}
```

OR simply

```
for i in mydict.items():
    for j in mydict.values():
        if i[1]!=j:
            if set(j).issuperset(set(i[1])):
                mydict.pop(i[0])

>>>mydict
{'GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAACGG': ['9/1', '9/2', '1/1.1', '9/2.1'],
 'GGGAAATTTCCCTTTGGGAAAGGG': ['1/1', '1/2', '9/1', '1/1.1']}
```

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly. Would you mind breaking it up a little. I am having a hard time understanding what exactly is going on.

Comment: crysis405: breaking it up yourself would be a good exercise so you could learn to write them on you own.

Comment: Yes, I will definity have a go. Thank you