# How to find the greatest superset set using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the greatest superset from some sets using Python.  However, there is a possibility that the greatest superset is not one, so I am wondering how to write the code. For example, how do I write a code to search the greatest supersets from following set?

```
# sample sets (dict format)
sample = {
    "mammalian" : set(['dog', 'cat', 'horse']),
    "bird" : set(['hawk', 'sparrow', 'pigeon']),
    "animal" : set(['dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'hawk', 'sparrow', 'pigeon']),
    "fruits" : set(['apple', 'strawberry']),
    "grain" : set(['corn', 'wheat', 'rice']),
    "plant" : set(['apple', 'strawberry', 'corn', 'wheat', 'rice'])
```

In this case, the greatest supersets are "animal" and "plant". I once wrote the code as follows, but I feel that my code was not pythonic at all. Please give me some advice or comments to improve my code.

Thanks.

```
# my code
keys = list(sample.keys())

candidate = []
candidate.append(keys[0]) 
for competitor in sample:
    comp_set = sample[competitor]
    flag = True
    for i in range(len(candidate)):
        cand_set = candidate[i]

        if cand_set >= comp_set:
            flag = False
        elif comp_set >= cand_set:
            candidate[i] = competitor
            flag = False
        elif flag and (i == len(candidate)-1):
            candidate.append(competitor)

candidate = set(candidate)

print(candidate) # {'plant', 'animal'}
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14106121/2301450)

Comment: Thank you for your very rapid comment! As you said, my question is almost the same as the previous question you commented. So, I will read the previous question, and close this question. Thank you, again!