# I have an iterator object which contains sets. I need to remove the supersets

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, iterator

I have an iterator object which contains sets. I need to remove the supersets.

```
input = [{1},{2,3},{1,2},{1,2,3},{2,3,5}]
```

the output should be `[{1},{2,3}]`. `{1,2}` is removed because `{1}` is a subset and etc.

I cant convert it to a list as it is a very expensive memory wise and timewise for my system as the list may contain a million elements . Is there an iterator operation to perform this operation or any inexpensive way to perform this?

Comment: Is it always that "shorter" sets are first? It would help a lot.

Comment: You need to remove supersets of *anything that's come __before__*…? Or do you need to compare every element to every element?

Comment: shorter sets don't necessarily come first

Comment: @deceze we need to compare every element to every element

Comment: That's a bit difficult without holding them all in memory… You could go through your iterator one by one and check if the element is a superset of any set you've encountered before. If not, you put it in a list. Then check the next element against said list and so on and so forth. But that requires you to hold the unique subsets in memory at least. Depending on how many you expect, that may be too much…

Comment: `any inexpensive way to perform this?` - That's at least `O(n^2)` because of the "every element to every element". "At least" because if the sets can long, it will be longer too. Memory-wise you'll need space for all results of yours.

Comment: Are all the sets different?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco all the sets are different

Comment: @h4z3 got the time complexity was wondering if there was any inbuilt way which is memory efficient way as well as fast

Comment: @KevinVizhalil Like deceze said - take one element, iterate and check `issuperset`. If current is not a superset to any, add to a result list. Take another. Check `issuperset` against the iterator content (and result list, if your iterator no longer had checked elements?). Repeat until you're out of elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient algorithm for finding all maximal subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106121/efficient-algorithm-for-finding-all-maximal-subsets)

Answer (score 1):

Why not shard your data? You can also use multiprocessing to speed things up. Based on what you are meaning, you can essentially get the unique subsets of all your "batches" and recompute again among all the subsets. This would save time if you already have your data in memory..and assuming that you are on a stream. you could again shard the streams and do this recursively which would speed it up. I don't see how to save memory that much, but time wise you can easily parallelize the problem.

Is the iterator working on a stream or something?

You can also note rules if len(someset) = 1.