# Is there a way to find semi-connected( unilaterally connected ) components in a directed graph with networkX?

Tags: algorithm, graph, networkx, directed-graph, connected-components

I don't know if this is a weird question. Like in the title, is there a way to find semi-connected( unilaterally connected ) components in a directed graph with networkX? I do read the document of networkX but it just has is_semiconnected to check if a di-graph is connected or not, i don't see any other option( am I missing anything?). What I want is something like nx.connected_components. For example I have a graph like this :[image]

I want the result to be : [A,B,C], [A,E,F], [X] and [Y]. The output data should be in the order, because in my case, A->B mean A happen before B,B->C mean B happen before C, so I want to keep the order as it is in the graph.  Is there a way to do this? If a node is not connected to any other node, it should be considered semi-connected too( for my case that i'm working ). Like in the example, if I have another standalone node called X, then X should be in the final answer too. I know this is kinda weird for directed graph, but need it for my data and output. It's like finding maximal semi-connected components.

Also i can make sure that my graph won't have cycles in it.

Comment: So it looks like you want all maximal semiconnected subgraphs.

Comment: How big is your graph?

Comment: Yeah, something liek all maximal semiconnected subgraphs. The size of the graph is depend on the input data, i can only say it could be around around like 1000-1500 edges i think. Again, it totally depends on the input data for my case

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an algorithm that makes effective use of NetworkX.

1. Compute the strong components of G and contract them, forming a directed acyclic graph.
2. Transitively reduce the DAG.
3. Enumerate all maximal paths in the DAG. (The technical wording of this step makes the previous step redundant, but after the transitive reduction, we can just enumerate all paths from a source to a sink.)
4. For each path, expand it back to the corresponding set of vertices in G.

Python implementation:

```py
import itertools
import networkx


def semiconnected_components(G):
    G0 = networkx.quotient_graph(G, list(networkx.strongly_connected_components(G)))
    G1 = networkx.transitive_reduction(G0)
    sources = {v for v in G1.nodes() if G1.in_degree(v) == 0}
    sinks = {v for v in G1.nodes() if G1.out_degree(v) == 0}
    for source in sources:
        for path in networkx.all_simple_paths(G1, source, sinks):
            yield list(itertools.chain(*map(sorted, path)))
    # Work around a bug in all_simple_paths (does not return length-0 paths, see
    # https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/6690).
    yield from map(list, sources & sinks)


def main():
    G = networkx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from({"X"})
    G.add_edges_from({"AB", "BC", "AE", "EF"})
    for S in semiconnected_components(G):
        print(S)
    print()
    G.add_edges_from({"CD", "DC", "CF"})
    for S in semiconnected_components(G):
        print(S)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'E', 'F']
['X']

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']
['A', 'E', 'F']
['X']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I will try it out. Also same as the comment i just add to Stef answer below, can we sort the node in the order from left to right? Cause with my data, A -> B mean A happen before B, B->C mean B happen before C,etc... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, i can make sure that my graph won't have cycles in it.

Comment: @CtMarvelous edited my answer to return ordered semicomponents. You could simplify it by skipping the quotient_graph call and just returning each path. Leaving it as is for other folks with the same question.

Comment: I just have check it out, sorry if i didn't clarify my problem in the first place. I forgot to say that if a node does not have edge to any other node, it should be considered semi-connected and should be in the final result to. Like in my example, if i have another node called X and it does not connect to any node, the result should be :
[A, B, C], [A, E, F], [X]. I will edit my original question too

Comment: @CtMarvelous I'm not sure I follow. Could you give the whole input and output you expect?

Comment: I just edit the orginal question David, are you ok with the problem? Sorry, i should have clarified in the first place.

Comment: If you need more information, just tell me @David Eisenstat . I hope that the problem is clear for you now. Sorry for my lack of description in the first place.

Comment: @CtMarvelous NetworkX has a [bug](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/6690). I edited this answer with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bruteforce function which will yield all maximally semiconnected subgraphs.

This uses a function `maximal_subsets(seq, pred)` to yield all maximal subsets of a sequence `seq` for a predicate `pred`.

You can find an explanation for that function in an answer to this related question:

- [Efficient algorithm for finding all maximal subsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106121/efficient-algorithm-for-finding-all-maximal-subsets)

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations
from collections import defaultdict
from networkx import is_semiconnected

def powerset_decreasing(iterable):
    "powerset_decreasing([1,2,3]) --> (1,2,3) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,) (2,) (3,)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s), 0, -1))

def maximal_subsets(seq, pred):
    cache = defaultdict(set)
    yielded_something = False
    for subset in powerset_decreasing(seq):
        supersets = set.intersection(*(cache[x] for x in subset))
        if (not supersets) and pred(subset):
            yield subset
            yielded_something = True
            for x in subset:
                cache[x].add(subset)
    if (not yielded_something) and pred(()):
        yield ()

def maximal_semiconnected_subgraphs(G):
    def pred(node_subset):
        return is_semiconnected(G.subgraph(node_subset))
    yield from maximal_subsets(G.nodes, pred)
```

Testing:

```py
## A -> B \    /> F -> G
##         > E 
## C -> D /    \> H -> I
from networkx import DiGraph
G = DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from('AB BE CD DE EF FG EH HI'.split())

components = [''.join(h) for h in maximal_semiconnected_subgraphs(G)]

print("COMPONENTS: ", components)
# COMPONENTS:  ['ABEFG', 'ABEHI', 'ECDFG', 'ECDHI']
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I just have a small things to ask. Can we sort the node in each component in order from left to right in the graph, cause my in my graph data, node from the left mean it should come first. Like in your example, with my situation, it would mean that C happen before D, D happen before E, E happen before H, etc.. So can we use something to sort the node in this order? once again, really grateful for your help.

Comment: I did edit my original question to clarify the problem more. You can see it again to understand more about what I want. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: @CtMarvelous If the graph is acyclic then instead of calling `maximal_subsets(G.nodes, pred)`, you can call `maximal_subsets(networkx.topological_sort(G), pred)`. If the graph is cyclic, then I'm afraid you have to sort each subset individually.

Comment: Yes i can make sure that with my data, the graph will be acyclic @Stef