# Is there a good data structure for finding all stored subsets of a given bitset?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, data-structures, subset

Let X be a set of distinct 64-bit unsigned integers `std::uint64_t`, each one being interpreted as a bitset representing a subset of {1,2,...,64}.

I want a function to do the following: **given a `std::uint64_t` A**, not necessarily in X, **list all B in X, such that B is a subset of A**, when A, B are interpreted as subsets of {1,2,...,64}.

*(Of course, in C++ this condition is just `(A & B) == B`).*

*Since A itself need not be in X*, I believe that this is not a duplicate of other questions.

**X will grow over time** (*but nothing will be deleted*), although there will be far more queries than additions to X.

I am free to choose the data structure representing the elements of X.

Obviously, we could represent X as a `std::set` or sorted `std::vector` of `std::uint64_t`, and I give one algorithm below. But can we do better?

**What are good data structures for X and algorithms** to do this efficiently? *This should be a standard problem but I couldn't find anything.*

**EDIT:** sorry if this is too vague. Obviously, if X were a `std::set` we could search through all subsets of A, taking time O(2^m log |X|) with m <= N, or all elements of X in time O(|X| log |X|).

Assume that in most cases, *the number of B is quite a bit smaller than both 2^m (the number of subsets of A) and |X|*. So, we want some kind of algorithm to run in time much less than |X| or 2^m in such cases, ideally in time O(number of B) but that's surely too optimistic. Obviously, O(|X|) cannot be beaten in the worst case.

Obviously **some memory overhead for X is expected**, and **memory is less of a bottleneck than time** for me. Using memory roughly 10 * (the memory of X stored as a `std::set`) is fine. Much more than this is too much. (*Asymptotically, anything more than O(|X|) or O(|X| log |X|) memory is probably too much*).

*Obviously, the use of C++ is not essential: the algorithms/data structures are the important things here.*

*In the case that X is fixed*, maybe **[Hasse diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) could work**.

It looks like Hasse diagrams would be quite time-consuming to construct each time X grows. (*But still maybe worth a try if nothing else comes up*). **EDIT:** maybe not so slow to update, so better than I thought.

**The below is just my idea so far;** maybe something better can be found?

**FINAL edit:** since it's closed, probably fairly - the "duplicate" question is pretty close - I won't bother with any further edits. I will probably do the below, but using a probabilistic skip list structure instead of a `std::set`, and augmented with skip distances (*so you can quickly calculate how many X elements remain in an interval, and thus reduce the number of search intervals, by switching to linear search when the intersection gets small*). This is similar to Order Statistic Trees given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751041/is-there-a-data-structure-like-a-c-std-set-which-also-quickly-returns-the-numb), but skip lists are a lot easier to reimplement than `std::set` (*especially as I don't need deletions*).

*Represent X as a `std::set` or sorted `std::vector` of 64-bit unsigned integers `std::uint64_t`, using the ordinary numerical order, and do recursive searches within smaller and smaller intervals.*

*E.g., my query element is A = 10011010.
Subsets of A containing the first bit lie in the inclusive interval [10000000, 10011010].*

*Subsets of A containing the second bit but not the first lie in the interval [00010000, 00011010].*

*Those with the third but not the second bit are in [00001000, 00001010].*

*Those with the fourth but not the third bit are in [00000010, 00000010].*

*Now, within the first interval [10000000, 10011010] you could make two subintervals to search, based on the second bit: [10000000, 10001010] and [10010000, 10011010].*

*Thus you can break it down recursively in this manner. The total length of search intervals is getting smaller all the time, so this is surely going to be better asymptotically than a trivial linear search through all of X.*

*E.g., if X = {00000010, 00001000, 00110111, 10011100} then only the first, third, fourth depth-1 intervals would have nonempty intersection with X. The final returned result would be [00000010, 00001000].*

*Of course this is unbalanced if the X elements are distributed fairly uniformly. We might want the search intervals to have roughly equal width at each depth, and they don't; above, the sizes of the four depth-1 search intervals are, I think, 27, 11, 3, 1, and for larger N the discrepancies could be much bigger.*

*If there are k bits in the query set A, then you'll have to construct k initial search intervals at depth 1 (searching on ONE bit), then up to 2k search intervals at depth 2, 4k at depth 3, etc.*

*If I've got it right, since log |X| = O(N) the number of search intervals is O(k + 2k + 4k + ... + 2^n . k) = O(k^2) = O(N^2), where 2^n = O(k), and each one takes O(N) time to construct (actually a bit less since it's the log of a smaller number, but the log doesn't increase much), so it seems like this is an O(N^3) algorithm to construct the search intervals.*

*Of course the full algorithm is not O(N^3), because each interval may contain many elements, so listing them all cannot be better than O(2^N) in general, but let's ignore this and assume that there are not enough elements of X to overwhelm the O(N^3) estimate.*

*Another issue is that `std::map` cannot tell you how many elements lie within an interval (unlike a sorted `std::vector`) so you don't know when to break off the partitioning and search through all remaining X elements in the interval. Of course, you have an upper bound on the number of X elements (the size of the full interval) but it may be quite poor.*

**EDIT: the answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751041/is-there-a-data-structure-like-a-c-std-set-which-also-quickly-returns-the-numb)** shows how to have a `std::set`-like structure which also quickly gives you the number of elements in a range, which obviously could be adapted to `std::map`-like structures. This would work well here for pruning  (*although annoying that, for C++, you'd have to reimplement most of `std::map`!*)

Comment: I think the partition can also be describe as "with first set bit" and "without first set bit". (which essentially a compact version of binary tree)

Comment: Yes, exactly. At each stage we are partitioning into 2 subproblems, based on whether the next bit is set. However it could lead to a very unbalanced search because the later intervals (with the less significant bits) have smaller widths, so contain far fewer elements of X, so most of the bookkeeping effort seems inefficient.

Comment: Have you tried to research `skip list` or `avl tree` they are not 'bundled' into the language but are a good point to check.

Comment: "But can we do better?" -- Sorry, but that's a really bad question: You need to define a starting point (e.g. one of the implementations you proposed) first. Then, what operations do you need improved? You mention yourself that you could improve performance for lookup at the cost of insertion performance, but what are the criteria to tell whether one solution is better than the other? Lastly, what kind of "better" do you want? You could search for better performance, better asymptotic complexity (Big-O), less memory consumption.

Comment: @user5428643 if it's a binary tree, the unbalance should not be a problem since the depth **is** `|X|`.

Comment: @IlianZapryanov Thanks, but skip lists and AVL trees look like they're for totally ordered collections. I don't see how they would apply to a collection of sets, which is only partially ordered.

Comment: @user5428643 just a note, you only need 1 `\`` for inline code format. (3 work too).

Comment: @appleapple My proposed solution doesn't ONLY search within X, it also searches within the space of all length-N binary strings (which can be represented as ordinary large ints). If N is a bit larger, say N=1000, and we use dynamic_bitset instead of uint64, then the size of X is not really so important; having a relatively small |X| (compared with 2^1000) doesn't actually help much, as they can still be distributed across many N-bit intervals.

Comment: @user5428643 sorry, I misread your post when comment, I mean the universe (64 in the question). your method need more space (*probably*) because it want to mimic BFS, if you do DFS it should only need O(|U|) space at any timepoint.

Comment: It seems there is no specific algorithm, so I close this as dupe for [Fast Data structure for finding strict subsets (from a given list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512400/fast-data-structure-for-finding-strict-subsets-from-a-given-list)

Comment: for some reason SO show it as need focus, and not showing the link. Someone may edit  to include it in the Post. (I cannot edit now because it has pending review queue...)

Comment: @IlianZapryanov I don't know if it's what you meant, but following your comment about skip lists I believe I can utilise them to solve my problem quite well, as I explain in my final edit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

Treating your integers as strings of `0` and `1`, build a customized version of [patricia tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), with the following rule:

- During lookup, if `1` is the current input bit at a branch, continue down *both* subtrees

The collection of all valid leaf nodes reached will be the answer.

#### Complexity

Let *n* be size of X,

Time: O(n)

- Worst case `-1`, when all subtrees are traversed. Complexity is bound by total number of nodes, stated below

Space: O(n)

- Number of nodes in a patricia tree is exactly 2n - 1

#### Rationale

Given that your match condition is `(A & B) == B`, a truth table is thus:

| . | A0 | A1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B0 | T | T |
| B1 | F | T |

Hence, during lookup, we collect both subtrees on a branch node when the input bit is `1`.

Comment: This looks like it should work so I'll accept it. It seems similar to the above two approaches with Hasse diagrams, and creation of search intervals within either a binary search tree or a skip list, but I suppose most reasonable algorithms for this problem would be vaguely similar, unless someone comes up with a really weird new algorithm.